# How to implement authentication mechanism in Java EE 6

Tags: java, security, authentication, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I'm trying to learn Java EE 6 and i'm just wondering how to implement authentication mechanism in Java EE 6.

Here is the Java EE 6 authentiction example:

```
    public void login() {
    if (account.authenticate(name, password) == null) {
        message = "Invalid user name or password!";
    } else {
        message = " Login successful";
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.login(this.name, this.password);
            Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
            name = principal.getName();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a following questions:

1. How request.login function check name and password? It isn't know user entity?
2. If it isn't right way. How to implement standart authentication mechanism

In finally thank you for your advise and i need a very good tutorials or advise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How `request.login` function check name and password? It isn't know user entity?

The [`request.login`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) allows to implement programmatic security and *validates the provided username and password in the **password validation realm** used by the web container login mechanism configured for the ServletContext*.

In other words, it delegates the authentication check to the container and this check is done against the security realm of the webapp. This is a **very nice** alternative to FORM-based authentication.

[Authentication Without the Form](http://blogs.oracle.com/bobby/entry/authentication_without_the_form) <strike>has</strike> had a nice [screencast](http://mediacast.sun.com/users/bbissett/media/ee6_auth.swf) showing this feature in action. If you don't want to use a file realm but a JDBC realm, check [this blog post](http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html).

#### See also

- [Summary of new Security Features in Servlet 3.0](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kumarjayanti/archive/2009/12/28/summary-new-security-features-servlet-30)
- [New Security Features in Glassfish v3 (Java EE 6) - Part III](http://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/new_security_features_in_glassfish2)
- [Leveraging Servlet 3.0 - Authentication without Forms using GlassFish v3 and Vaadin](http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/vaadin_and_glassfish_v3_html)
- [JDBC Realm Setup with Glassfish v3 (build 70) and Netbeans 6.8 (beta) JEE6](http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html)

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I love Java and Java EE.

Comment: @Zeck: Java EE 6 is terrific!

Comment: why do you say that it's an "alternative to FORM-based authentication", on the screencast the the login/passwd box looks really like a <form>, no? (or maybe we're not talking about the same kind of form?)

Comment: @Kevin Both solutions rely on a form but [Form-Based authentication](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3669/bncbq?a=view) forces you to use a **dedicated** page for the form. This is not the case here which is why I consider it as a much nicer alternative.

Comment: IMO the login and autheticate methods of HSR are misplaced. Regular users should not be using form based logins at all. You don't want plaintext credentials to exist on your server even if it is only briefly and ideally you don't want users typing passwords into browser-space at all if you can help it. Use SSO. Either cloud SSO so that you're funneling all users to an IdP server or, if you're in a corp environment use Windows builtin SSO like Keberos / NTLM.